# Парсер видео youtube по ссылке

Tags: php, json, парсер, youtube, youtube-api

Имеется давольно старый код, который парсит видео ютуба по ссылке

```
<?

require_once('libs/JSON.php');
$json = new Services_JSON();

function youtube($url){
global $uid, $json;
 if(!ereg("http://", $url))$url = "http://".$url;
 $pars_url = parse_url($url);
 parse_str($pars_url["query"]);
 $html = str_replace('$', '', @file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/".$v."?alt=json"));
 $video = $json->decode($html);
  $video_array = (array) $video->entry;
 //print_R($video_array["title"]->t);
 //print_R($video->entry->content);
  if($video_array["title"]->t){

   $video_image = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/".$v."/0.jpg";
   $video_simage = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/".$v."/2.jpg";
   $out["url"] = $url;
   $out["title"] = iconv("utf-8", "windows-1251",  str_replace(array("\n" ,"\r", '"',"/"),array('\n' ,'\r', '\"', ""), $video_array["title"]->t));
   $out["description"] = iconv("utf-8", "windows-1251", str_replace(array("\n" ,"\r", '"',"/"),array('\n' ,'\r', '\"', "\/"),$video_array["content"]->t));
   $out["images"] = array($video_image, $video_simage);
   $out["domain"] = $pars_url["host"];
   $out["duration"] = $video_array["mediagroup"]->ytduration->seconds;
   $out["error"]  = "1";
   $out["vid"] = $v;
   $out["uid"] = $uid;
   $out["hash"] = md5($uid.$out["vid"]."youtube_add".date("ym").$out["duration"].$video_image.$video_simage);
  }else{
   $out["error"]  = "2";
  }
  //print_R($out);
  return $out;
}

?>
```

Данный метод давно не работает. Где нужно править, что бы работало?
Заранее благодарю..

Comment: А где именно не работает? Вы ошибки смотрели, которые скрипт показывает? Понятное дело, раз на выходе ответа нет, то не работает. Что содержится в возвращаемом `$out`?

Comment: В $out информация о видео(название, описание, привью и vid(айди видео)).
Это движок полностью самопис.

Comment: Не важно, самопис или нет, и в `$out` понятное дело хранится информация о ролике. На данный момент что возвращает скрипт и какие сыпет ошибки?

Comment: Для начала: 1. Замените фунцию `ereg` на `preg_match`, `ereg` является устаревшей функцией. 2. Функция не знает переменную $v. 3. Избавьтесь от подавителя ошибок `@`

Answer (score 1):

[Найдено](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896233/how-can-i-retrieve-youtube-video-details-from-video-url-using-php) на просторах enSO (да простит меня сообщество). **Альтернативный вариант**:

```
function get_youtube($url){
    $youtube = "http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=". $url ."&format=json";
    $curl = curl_init($youtube);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $return = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return json_decode($return, true);
}

$url = // youtube video url 

// Display Data 
print_r(get_youtube($url));
```

Проверил, работает. Конкретно по Вашему коду: если в наглую перейти по генерируемой ссылке, то сервис отвечает, что сервис не работает (но может у меня руки корявые).

Есть **еще один вариант**, на самой взгляд, самый геморойный: использовать [Google Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/)

Comment: Да не, не особо геморно использовать api youtube. Единственное только, в бесплатной версии там ограничения некоторые, но если не задаваться целью выпотрошить весь ютуб от начала времён, то норм.